# what is the difference between pathpattern and antpathmatcher in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
what is the difference between pathpattern and antpathmatcher in spring mvc?
```

> what is the difference between pathpattern and antpathmatcher in spring mvc?

Answer (score 0):

The reason `PathPattern` was introduced is explained in details in [this post on spring.io](https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/30/url-matching-with-pathpattern-in-spring-mvc). Here're few excerpts from the post:

> In Spring applications `AntPathMatcher` is used to identify classpath, file system, remote, and other resources in Spring configuration. It has also been used in Spring MVC to match URL paths. Over time the use of patterns in web applications grew in number and syntax with `AntPathMatcher` evolving to meet those needs but some pain points remain without a solution.

> The introduction of Spring WebFlux in Spring Framework 5.0 was a good opportunity to re-think all this and to create an alternative.

With `PathPattern`:

> Patterns are parsed on startup and re-used at runtime for efficient URL matching. How much more efficient? It’s hard to give numbers without a concrete use case but our jmh benchmark shows 6-8 times the throughput and 30-40% reduction in allocation rate.

> `PathPattern` is compatible with `AntPathMatcher` syntax except couple cases (listed in the post.)

Comment: `Patterns are parsed on startup`, Is it possible to get this as a Bean and use it in user code?